# pushwoosh new jar makes my push notification to handle twice

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, pushwoosh

since i have update pushwoosh lib my notification is shown twice, once as i handle with my custom receiver and another probably with the pushwoosh receiver.

how do i disable pushwoosh handling?

i have added this in my manifest:

```
     <meta-data android:name="PW_NOTIFICATION_RECEIVER" android:value="MYPACKAGE.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"/>
```

still having this problem, as i wrote my custom receiver (C2DMBroadcastReceiver) works as he should but i need to disable pushwoosh handling to avoid double notification...

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to see your code (or at least logs or AndroidManifest.xml)? Link to pastebin for example?

PW_NOTIFICATION_RECEIVER is just a handler for the push tap. Notification is created by the SDK itself. It's hard to say without seeing a code.